# Get Element by ID from AJAX response table

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Helo all

i've a problem with selecting/getting element ID from ajax response

Here's my code

script.js :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    createPagination(0);
    function createPagination(pageNum){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/bulus-ci/budget/pagination/'+pageNum,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response.budget);
                $('#pagination_link').html(response.pagination_link);
                paginationData(response.budget);
            }
        });
    }
    function paginationData(data) {
        $('#budget_table tbody').empty();
        for(budget in data){
            var budgetRow = "<tr>";
            budgetRow += '<td class="bg-info text-light">'+ data[budget].budget_id +'</td>';
            budgetRow += "<td>"+ data[budget].carline +"</td>";
            budgetRow += "<td>"+ data[budget].delivery_plan +"</td>"
            budgetRow += "<td>"+ data[budget].subgroup +"</td>"
            budgetRow += "<td>"+ data[budget].item_desc +"</td>"
            budgetRow += "<td>"+ data[budget].curr +"</td>";
            budgetRow += "<td>"+ data[budget].price_ori +"</td>";
            budgetRow += "<td>"+ data[budget].qty_ori +"</td>";
            budgetRow += "<td>"+ data[budget].amount_ori_usd +"</td>";
            budgetRow += '<td> <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="'+data[budget].id +'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailExpenseModal" class="badge badge-primary detailExpenseModal">detail</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="'+data[budget].id +'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editExpenseModal" class="badge badge-success editExpenseModal">edit</a> <a href="http://localhost/bulus-ci/budget/commit_expense/'+data[budget].id +'" class="badge badge-secondary tombol-commit">commit</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="'+data[budget].id +'" data-budgetid="'+data[budget].id +'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteExpenseModal" class="badge badge-danger tombol-hapus">delete</a>';
            $('#budget_table tbody').append(budgetRow);                 
        }
    }   
});
</script>
```

view.php :

```
<div class="card-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="budget_table" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Budget ID</th>
                <th>Carline</th>
                <th>Delivery Plan</th>
                <th>Subgroup</th>
                <th>Item Desc</th>
                <th>Curr</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Amount(USD)</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div align="right" id="pagination_link"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the view.php looks like after getting the response from ajax :
[image: view.php]

and now i'm trying to select the class of-> *tombol-commit* , using jQuery selector by using these codes :

```
$('a.badge.badge-secondary.tombol-commit').on('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('aaaaaa');
})
```

it doesn't work, 
i have tried using :

1. find()
2. filter()
3. direct select -> $('a.badge.badge-secondary.tombol-commit')

But still the alert won't come
can someone help me with this

notes :
this is the page source looks like after getting the ajax response
[image]

Comment: what is `response` here  i.e : `$(response).find...`
?

Comment: @Swati It's a json object, and will be fetched to #budget_table as you can see on my script above, before i use find/filter , i tried to select directly using ---> $('a.badge.badge-secondary.tombol-commit') and doesn't work,

Comment: @Swati i changed my selector code to simplify the question

Comment: Simply write `$(document).on("click", ".tombol-commit", function(){ alert("hi"); });` and check onces
 `

Comment: @Swati thaaaaanks a lot, this 100% works, so the key is i have to put $(document) first right ?

Comment: As you are creating your element `dynamically` , you need to bind your event to some `static` element which doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax,

$(document).on("click" , " #id_name" , function () { alert("​ test "); });